# After indexing the mysql not picking up the index

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

i have already shared the below Query ref: [index not working for the below query.why? mysql version- 8.0.29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74093385/index-not-working-for-the-below-query-why-mysql-version-8-0-29)

Query;

```
select  journey_level, 
        src_screen_name from_entity_name, 
        src_screen_id from_entity_id, 
        dest_screen_name to_entity_name, 
        dest_screen_id to_entity_id, 
        dest_screen_id to_entity_id_list, 
        concat(journey_level, '-', src_screen_id, '-', src_screen_name)
        from_entity, 
        concat(journey_level + 1, '-', dest_screen_id ,'-', dest_screen_name) to_entity, 
        count(1) cnt, 
        sum(ifnull(is_crash, 0)) crash_cnt, 
        sum(ifnull(is_anr, 0)) anr_cnt, 
        sum(ifnull(is_rage, 0) ) rage_cnt, 
        case dest_screen_id when -1 then 'Red' else '' end node_color 
from ue_summary.user_journey_screens_1943 s 
where first_session_created_at >= '2022-09-17 00:00:00' and first_session_created_at <='2022-10-17 10:42:35' 
and s.platform = '1' 
and journey_level <= '4' 
group by  journey_level, from_entity_id, from_entity_name, to_entity_id, to_entity_name;
```

Explain plan;

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: date_platform_level,platform_date,idx_platform
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 556941160
     filtered: 1.67
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary
```

Table structure;

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `user_journey_screens_1943` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `asi` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_session_created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_task_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_version_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `journey_level` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `src_screen_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `src_screen_name` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `src_capture_time` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `src_capture_time_relative` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest_screen_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest_screen_name` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest_capture_time` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest_capture_time_relative` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_crash` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_anr` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_rage` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `app_id_date_level` (`app_id`,`first_session_created_at`,`journey_level`),
  KEY `asi` (`asi`),
  KEY `date_platform_level` (`first_session_created_at`,`platform`,`journey_level`),
  KEY `platform_date` (`platform`,`first_session_created_at`),
  KEY `idx_platform` (`platform`,`first_session_created_at`,`journey_level`,`src_screen_id`,`src_screen_name`,`dest_screen_id`,`dest_screen_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2100241774 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

i have used a forced index too but still no improvements in the performance, is there any way if had kindly share your thoughts.

After force index;

```
explain 
select 
  s.journey_level, 
  src_screen_name from_entity_name, 
  src_screen_id from_entity_id, 
  dest_screen_name to_entity_name, 
  dest_screen_id to_entity_id, 
  dest_screen_id to_entity_id_list, 
  concat(
    journey_level, '-', src_screen_id, 
    '-', src_screen_name
  ) from_entity, 
  concat(
    journey_level + 1, '-', dest_screen_id, 
    '-', dest_screen_name
  ) to_entity, 
  count(1) cnt, 
  sum(
    ifnull(is_crash, 0)
  ) crash_cnt, 
  sum(
    ifnull(is_anr, 0)
  ) anr_cnt, 
  sum(
    ifnull(is_rage, 0)
  ) rage_cnt, 
  case dest_screen_id when -1 then 'Red' else '' end node_color 
from 
  ue_summary.user_journey_screens_1943 s force index(platform_date) 
  where 
first_session_created_at >= '2022-09-17 00:00:00' and first_session_created_at <='2022-10-17 10:42:35' 
    and s.platform = '1' 
    and journey_level <= '4' 
    group by  journey_level, from_entity_id, from_entity_name, to_entity_id, to_entity_name;
```

also removed the quotes of the int column.
row scans;

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: platform_date
          key: platform_date
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 278684615
     filtered: 33.33
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: date_platform_level
          key: date_platform_level
      key_len: 13
          ref: NULL
         rows: 278691741
     filtered: 33.33
        Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary
```

but still, the performance of the query is low.

Comment: It seems that you have the correct index present  `KEY  date_platform_level  (first_session_created_at,platform,journey_level) `, I suggest only  removing quotes from and s.platform = '1'  and journey_level <= '4'

Comment: i have removed and given a force index for that index the execution time is not that much good taking 5 min to execute @ErgestBasha

Comment: The rows scan decreased from 556941160 to 278691741

Comment: yup, but the execution is crossing 5 min.

Comment: If this is a common type of query, then building and maintaining a daily [_Summary Table_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) may be the best option.

Comment: @ErgestBasha - The quotes matter only for `varchar_col = unquoted_number`.

Comment: is there any other way to optimize the Query? @RickJames

Comment: @meritonissac - Are there really 278M rows with that platform in that month?  Are most of the rows platform=1?

Comment: I guess so, can you suggest both ideas whether what it has and what it does not...@RickJames